# Mysql: Concatenate Duplicate Data but ignore string in duplicates

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-5.7, fuzzy-comparison

Is there a way to find duplicate data while ignoring a given string?

For example if I have a table of names, is there a way to concatenate rows that both have the name "Ann Smith" but ignore the string "Dr. ". For example rows containing "Ann Smith" and "Dr. Ann Smith" should concatenate into one row that takes the name "Dr. Ann Smith". If the names match (minus the "dr." string) and the addresses of the two rows match, concatenate phone numbers. I'd like to take the larger of the two names, which I think would involve using the MAX statement.

Currently I have a table called t:

```
name          | phone      | address
ann smith     | 1234567899 | 123 home address
dr. ann smith | 1234567890 | 123 home address
brian smith   | 1235551234 | 789 city street
```

I want to get to:

```
name          | phone                  | address
dr. ann smith | 1234567890, 1234567899 | 123 home address
brian smith   | 1235551234             | 789 city street
```

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results, in a tabular format.

Comment: Sorry about that.

Comment: This is not really about concatenation, this is about fuzzy matching, which is not that easy to do.

Comment: if "given string" is static value and it is "Dr. ", may be something simlar to this: `select name  from t group by replace(name, 'Dr. ', '')` ?

Comment: What happens when you have two strings with the same length? Which one do you pick? Any one randomly?

Comment: MySQL 8, or MySQL 5.x?

Comment: Either work. I don't think that will be the case though. I have another statement before that concatenates everything that have exact matches for name and address. So this would only be if the two names were an exact match but one has the string "dr. " in front of it.

Comment: My version is mysql 5.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do what you want you probably need CTEs (Common Table Expressions), and `LATERAL` queries. Unfortunately MySQL 5.x does not implement either of them.

The following query finds the duplicate names:

```
select plain_name, count(*)
  from (
    select name, trim(replace(lower(name), lower('Dr.'), '')) as plain_name
      from my_table
  ) x
  group by plain_name
  having count(*) > 1
```

This is a step in the right direction, but you'll need to process further to get the result you want.

If you upgrade to MySQL 8 you will get CTEs, but still won't get LATERAL queries.

**Edit:** I went a step further to identify the duplicate names. Without CTEs this query is looking increasingly uglier:

```
select z.*, y.times
  from (
    select name, trim(replace(lower(name), lower('Dr.'), '')) as plain_name
      from my_table
  ) z,
  (
    select plain_name, count(*) as times
      from (
        select name, trim(replace(lower(name), lower('Dr.'), '')) as plain_name
          from my_table
      ) x
      group by plain_name
      having count(*) > 1
  ) y
  where z.plain_name = y.plain_name;
```

Comment: I'm getting an error about not having x.name in the group by.. Should I add that to the group by statement?

Comment: Fixed. I added an extra processing step to help identifying the duplicate rows.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming these are exactly nested, you can get the "long form" by doing:

```
select name,
       (select t2.name
        from t t2
        where t2.name like concat('%', t.name, '%')
        order by length(t2.name) desc
        limit 1
       ) as long_form
from t;
```

You can then use this in an aggregation.  I would use a subquery:

```
select long_form, group_concat(distinct phone) as phones,
       group_concat(distinct address) as addresses
from (select t.*,
             (select t2.name
              from t t2
              where t2.name like concat('%', t.name, '%')
              order by length(t2.name) desc
              limit 1
             ) as long_form
      from t
     ) tt
group by long_from;
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a combination of the above answers. First I created a temporary table that trims and replaces the 'Dr. ' string with an empty string.

```
create temporary table if not exists temp_names AS (
select *, 
    case when name like lower('dr. %') then trim(replace(lower(name), lower('dr. %'), ''))
    else name end as plain_name from t);
```

Then I use a select and a group by to concatenate values in that table with the same plain_name value.

```
select max(name) as name, group_concat(distinct phone_number) as phone_number, address from temp_names 
    group by plain_name, address having count(*) >=1;
```

This gives a table with the desired results:

```
name          | phone_number           | address
dr. ann smith | 1234567890, 1234567899 | 123 home address
brian smith   | 1235551234             | 789 city street
```